# upgrade to xubuntu 14.04 broke the perlbrew

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

I upgraded my xubuntu 13.10 (x86_54) to 14.04. The resulting 14.04 has the following problems:

- The $PATH variable now contains only these two entries:

  - /home/myuid/perl5/bin
  - /home/myuid/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin
- The system also complains: Can't locate App/perlbrew.pm in @INC

Please note that I do have perlbrew.pm in: /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/App/perlbrew.pm.

I'd appreciate very much some help in getting the perlbrew to run. Hopefully without having to re-install perlbrew in the new version. Nor go back to the old xubuntu 13.10.

I'd also like to understand how this happened.

Comment: The version of perl changed between 13.10 and 14.04. Afaik since you manually installed perlbrew (outside of apt) this means you need to manually reinstall perlbrew. It is not really related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @bain Software *not* installed through Ubuntu's package manager ("Third-party applications") [is still on-topic here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), actually. So you might want to post an answer--your comment does seem to give the solution for this.